# How to retrieve cookies from Guzzle client?

Tags: php, guzzle

How can I retrieve the cookies from a Guzzle request / client, after a request has occurred?

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'www.google.com',
]);
$response = $client->request('GET', '/');
```

Comment: Look here: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies

Comment: I've tried that but it appears the file just remains an empty json array `[]`.

Comment: You should make sure you're in the right scope. for closures, you can say `function() use($someArray){}` to pass in a reference of that array. (make the array before this!)

Comment: Also please post what you've already tried so that we can work off that :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Read [the docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies), please. You have to use `CookieJar` class to work with cookies.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['cookies' => true]);
$r = $client->request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/cookies');

$cookieJar = $client->getConfig('cookies');
$cookieJar->toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To be fair, the documentation doesn't mention how to access cookies from Guzzle. Only how to provide a CookieJar instance to a request. It doesn't even explain how to interact with a CookieJar instance.

Comment: `getConfig` is deprecated by now.

Answer (score 4):

just updating this post.

In Guzzle version 8.0, the `getConfig()` method will be `@deprecated`. [Read the docs.](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2514)

You can get cookies, from sample code:

```
$client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'YOUR_URI',
    ]);
    
$response = $client->post('PATH');

$headerSetCookies = $response->getHeader('Set-Cookie');

$cookies = [];
foreach ($headerSetCookies as $key => $header) {
    $cookie = SetCookie::fromString($header);
    $cookie->setDomain('YOUR_DOMAIN');

    $cookies[] = $cookie;
}

$cookieJar = new CookieJar(false, $cookies);
```

For use, then:

```
$client->post('PATH', [
    'cookies' => $cookieJar
]);
```