# How to get the cookies from the riotgames auth API?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, riot-games-api

Using the riotgames auth API, I am trying to get my access token and cookies using the following request:

I did use GuzzleHttp\Client for sending request

```
//for get cookies 
$client = new Client();
// Constructing the request body as an array
$requestBody = [
    'client_id' => 'play-valorant-web-prod',
    'nonce' => '1',
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://playvalorant.com/opt_in',
    'response_type' => 'token id_token',
    'scope' => 'account openid'
];
// Sending a POST request to the specified endpoint
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://auth.riotgames.com/api/v1/authorization', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
    RequestOptions::JSON => $requestBody,
]);
```

and this for get token

```
$response = $client->request('PUT', 'https://auth.riotgames.com/api/v1/authorization', [
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
    'json' => [
        'type' => 'auth',
        'username' => $your_username_variable,
        'password' => $your_password_variable,
    ],
]);
$json = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

I try to use this package https://github.com/Seaony/laravel-valorant-api
and https://valapidocs.techchrism.me/endpoint/auth-cookies

I think the problem has relationship with API key that riot games API give it when create account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve cookies from Guzzle client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022631/how-to-retrieve-cookies-from-guzzle-client)